# Combined tree with several marriages

Tags: positioning, genealogytree

I am trying to create a genealogy tree that is a bit unusual.

The issue is that the ancestor has had three wives and I want to show this in the tree.

However I still want to make it clear which of the families is the important one (for me).

So the idea is that the ancestor and his third wife get placed centrally.

Above them would be their parents, below them the children. Nothing unusual.

However to the left of the husband I want to show the previous marriages ordered top to bottom, including the parents of the previous spouses.

I've added the additional families following the example here:

[Aligning nodes in tikz / genealogytree package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278745/aligning-nodes-in-tikz-genealogytree-package)

but they overwrite each other.

Is there a way to move the one family a bit up and the 2nd one down?

In addition, I would like to have the additional subtrees to have smaller boxes. If I try to use smaller boxes, the main person also gets a smaller box and this doesn't look good.

Code is here:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{report}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape,layoutoffset={0pt,0pt},hscale=0.85, vscale=0.9, inner=15mm, top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{male/.style={colframe=black, colback=blue!06, watermark text=\gtrSymbolsSetDraw{blue!16}\gtrsymMale}}
\tcbset{female/.style={colframe=black, colback=red!07, watermark text=\gtrSymbolsSetDraw{red!17}\gtrsymFemale}}

\gtrset{
  box={colback=white},
  edges={swing,no background,foreground=black!50},
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Adam Winklhofer and his third wife Susanna Urlhardt
  \genealogytree[timeflow=down,
  % tree offset=0.4 cm,
  level size=3 cm,
  node  size=5 cm,
  level distance=1.25 cm,
  child distance=1.75 cm,
  parent distance=2.5 cm,
  further distance = 3 cm
  ]
  {
    sandclock
    {% main couple
      parent
      {
        g[male, id=I01254_1]{Adam Winklhofer}
      }
      parent
      {
        g[female, id=I01255_1]{Susanna Urlhardt}
      }
      c[male,id=I01301]{Thomas Winklhofer}
    }
  }

  % Adam Winklhofer and his first wife Apollonia
  \genealogytree[timeflow=down, set position=I01254_2 at I01254_1,
  box={colback=white},
  edges={swing,no background,foreground=black!50},
  level size=3 cm,
  node  size=5 cm,
  level distance=1.75 cm,
  child distance=1.25 cm,
  parent distance=0.1 cm,
  further distance = 3 cm
  ]
  {
    sandclock
    {% his family
      parent
      {%
        g[female, id=I01271]{Apollonia NN}%
      }
      parent
      {%
        g[male, id=I01254_2]{Adam Winklhofer}%
      }
      child
      {% Barbara
        g[female,id=I01265]{Barbara Winklhofer}
      }
    }
  }

  % Adam Winklhofer and his second wife Maria Moser
  \genealogytree[timeflow=down, set position=I01254_3 at I01254_1,
  box={colback=white},
  edges={swing,no background,foreground=black!50},
  level distance=1.75 cm,
  child distance=1.25 cm,
  parent distance=0.1 cm,
  further distance = 3 cm
  ]
  {
    sandclock
    {% his family
      parent
      {%
        g[female,id=I01262]{Maria Moser}%
        parent {
          g[male,id=I01264]{Wolfgang Moser}
        }
        parent {
          g[female,id=I01429]{Rosina Kendmayr}
        }
      }
      parent
      {%
        g[male, id=I01254_3]{Adam Winklhofer}%
      }
      child
      {%
        g[male,id=I01251]{Georg Winklhofer}
      }
    }
  }

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used some `xshift` to adjust the positions of the family members and I've drawn the main family after the others to avoid undesired overlapping.

I hope this is more or less what you're looking for.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{report}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape,layoutoffset={0pt,0pt},hscale=0.85, vscale=0.9, inner=15mm, top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

    \tcbset{male/.style={colframe=black, colback=blue!06, watermark text=\gtrSymbolsSetDraw{blue!16}\gtrsymMale}}
    \tcbset{female/.style={colframe=black, colback=red!07, watermark text=\gtrSymbolsSetDraw{red!17}\gtrsymFemale}}

    \gtrset{
        box={colback=white},
        edges={swing,no background,foreground=black!50},
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Adam Winklhofer and his first wife Apollonia
    \genealogytree[timeflow=down, 
    box={colback=white},
    edges={swing,no background,foreground=black!50},
    level size=2 cm,
    node  size=4 cm,
    level distance=3.5 cm,
    child distance=1.25 cm,
    parent distance=0.1 cm,
    further distance = 3 cm
    ]
    {
        sandclock
        {% his family
            parent
            {%
                g[female, id=I01271,tikz={xshift=-2cm}]{Apollonia NN}%
            }
            parent
            {%
                g[male, id=I01254_2]{Adam Winklhofer}%
            }
            child
            {% Barbara
                g[female,id=I01265,tikz={xshift=-1cm}]{Barbara Winklhofer}
            }
        }
    }

    % Adam Winklhofer and his second wife Maria Moser
    \genealogytree[timeflow=down, set position=I01254_3 at I01254_2,
    box={colback=white},
    edges={swing,no background,foreground=black!50},
    level size=2 cm,
    node  size=4 cm,
    level distance=3.5 cm,
    child distance=1.25 cm,
    parent distance=0.1 cm,
    further distance = 3 cm
    ]
    {
        sandclock
        {% his family
            parent
            {%
                g[female,id=I01262,tikz={xshift=18cm}]{Maria Moser}%
                parent {
                    g[male,id=I01264,tikz={xshift=18cm}]{Wolfgang Moser}
                }
                parent {
                    g[female,id=I01429,tikz={xshift=18cm}]{Rosina Kendmayr}
                }
            }
            parent
            {%
                g[male, id=I01254_3]{Adam Winklhofer}%
            }
            child
            {%
                g[male,id=I01251,tikz={xshift=13cm}]{Georg Winklhofer}
            }
        }
    }

    % Adam Winklhofer and his third wife Susanna Urlhardt
    \genealogytree[timeflow=down,
    set position=I01254_1 at I01254_2,
    level size=3 cm,
    node  size=5 cm,
    level distance=2.5 cm,
    child distance=1.75 cm,
    parent distance=2.5 cm,
    further distance = 3 cm,
    ]
    {
        sandclock
        {% main couple
            parent
            {
                g[male, id=I01254_1]{Adam Winklhofer}
            }
            parent
            {
                g[female, id=I01255_1]{Susanna Urlhardt}
            }
            c[male,id=I01301]{Thomas Winklhofer}
        }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]