# {genealogytree} Multiple Family Trees (with Unions)

Tags: pdf, trees, genealogytree, genealogy

In the last few weeks, I've been working on the "genealogytree" package to draw my family trees.

Although I have read the manual up and down, I am unfortunately not able to merge my family trees from my point of view. (id = FeS) (yellow box)

Do you have tips for me how to place the trees correctly (and use the algorithm of the package for that) and get everything on a PDF page? 
At the moment i am cheating on this problem through scaling down my tress..

The first thing I wanted to do was to put the W and R families together in a tree. Later, however, all the other families. I also want to be able to draw a single Family Tree (Maybe my Cousin wants me to draw his other family part I am not included in.)

I've abbreviated first names, nicknames and surnames, taken out death- and birthdays, professions and comments to draw attention to the main problem.

Thank you in advance

Here's my **main Document**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\gtrset{
    processing=database,   
    database format=medium marriage below,
    node size=2.4cm,
    level size=3.5cm,
    level distance=6mm,
    list separators hang,
    name font=\bfseries,
    surn code={\textcolor{red!50!black}{#1}},
    place text={\newline}{},
    %date format=d/mon/yyyy,
    date format=d.mon.yyyy,
    tcbset={%Gender based design of Boxes
        male/.style={colframe=blue,colback=blue!5},
        female/.style={colframe=red,colback=red!5},
    },
    box={
        fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
        halign=flush left,before upper=\parskip1pt,
        \gtrDBsex
        ,drop fuzzy shadow,
        if image defined={add to width=25mm,right=25mm,
        underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\path[fill overzoom image=
        \gtrDBimage
        ]
        ([xshift=-24mm]interior.south east) rectangle (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
        }{},
    },
    edges=rounded, %Rounded Edges
    symbols record reset,
    after tree={
        \node[font=\scriptsize\itshape,text width=1.8cm,below left,
        fill=white,fill opacity=0.4,text opacity=1]
        at (current bounding box.north east){\gtrSymbolsLegend};
    },
    level 2/.style={level size=3cm,node size from=1cm to 2cm,node={turn,box={no shadow,drop fuzzy shadow southwest}}},
}
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\subsection{\textcolor{red}{Family W and Family R}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,transform shape]
    \genealogytree[ %Family W
        id suffix=@WTD,
    ]
    {
        input{./TopDown/W_TD.graph}
    }
    \genealogytree[%Family R
        id suffix=@RTD,
        %set Position=JoJoR@RTD at JoJoW@WTD,
    ]
    {
        input{./TopDown/R_TD.graph}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

**S_TD.graph**

```
sandclock{
    parent{
        %c[]{name={\pref{UrUrTante} \surn{S}},birth={0}{},death={0}{}}
        %c[]{name={\pref{UrUrOnkel} \surn{S}},birth={0}{},death={0}{}}
        g[]{male,name={\pref{UrUrOpa} \surn{S}},birth={0}{},death={0}{}}

    }
    parent{
        g[]{female,name={\pref{UrUrOma} \surn{a?}},birth={0}{},death={0}{}}
        %c[]{name={\pref{UrUrTante} \surn{a?}},birth={0}{},death={0}{}}
        %c[]{name={\pref{UrUrOnkel} \surn{a?}},birth={0}{},death={0}{}}

    }
    child{
        g[]{male,name={\pref{UrOpa} \surn{S}},birth={0}{},death={0}{}}
        p[]{female,name={\pref{UrOma} \surn{b?}},birth={0}{},death={0}{}}
%He        
        child{
            g[id=HeS]{male,name={\pref{He} \surn{S}}}
            p[id=AnK]{female,name={\pref{An} \surn{K}}}
    %Ho
            child{
                p[id=KaR]{female,name={\pref{Ka} \surn{R}}}
                g[id=HoS]{male,name={\pref{Ho} \surn{S}}}
                c[id=StS]{male,name={\pref{St} \surn{S}}}
                c[id=SeS]{male,name={\pref{Se} \surn{S}}}
            }
    %Th     
            child[id=Fam_S]{
                p[id=SuR]{female,name={\pref{Su} Ma \nick{Su} \surn{R}}}
                g[id=ThS]{male,name={\pref{Th} \nick{To} \surn{S}}}
                c[id=KaS]{male,name={\pref{Ka} Mi \surn{S}}}
                c[id=FeS]{male,name={\pref{Fe} \surn{S}}}
                union[id=Fam_S->B,family box={colback=yellow!50}]{
                    p[id=MaF]{female,name={\pref{Ma} \surn{F}}}
                    c[id=LeB]{female,name={\pref{Le} \surn{B}}}
                    c[id=GrB]{female,name={\pref{Gr} \surn{B}}}
                }
            }
    %Pe
            child{
                g[id=PeS]{female,name={\pref{Pe} \surn{S}}}
                p[id=JuK]{male,name={\pref{Ju} \surn{K}}}
                c[id=ChK]{male,name={\pref{Ch} \surn{K}}}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**W_TD.graph**

```
sandclock{
    parent{
        %c\[\]{female,name={\pref{UrUrTante} \surn{W}},birth={0}{},death={0}{}}
        %c\[\]{male,name={\pref{UrUrOnkel} \surn{W}},birth={0}{},death={0}{}}
        g\[id=LuW\]{male,name={\pref{Lu} \surn{W}}}
    }
    parent{
        g\[id=JoW\]{female,name={\pref{Jo} An \nick{Jo} \surn{W}}}
        %c\[\]{female,name={\pref{UrUrTante} \surn{a?}},birth={0}{},death={0}{}}
        %c\[\]{male,name={\pref{UrUrOnkel} \surn{a?}},birth={0}{},death={0}{}}
    }
    child{
        p\[id=GrN\]{female,name={\pref{Gr} \surn{N}}}
        g\[id=HeW\]{male,name={\pref{He} \surn{W}}}
        c\[phantom\]{}
    }
    child{
        g\[id=KaW\]{male,name={\pref{Ka} \surn{W}}}
        p\[id=ElW\]{female,name={\pref{El} \surn{W}}}
%Lu
        child{
            p\[id=InT\]{female,name={\pref{In} \surn{T}}}
            g\[id=LuW\]{male,name={\pref{Lu} \surn{W}}}
            c\[id=JoW\]{male,name={\pref{Jo} \surn{W}}}
            child{
                g\[id=ElW\]{female,name={\pref{El} Ma \surn{W}}}
                p\[id=ToO\]{male,name={\pref{To} \surn{O}}}
                child{
                    p\[id=AnL\]{male,name={\pref{An} \surn{L}}}
                    g\[id=AnO\]{female,name={\pref{An} \surn{O}}}
                    c\[id=AstridW\]{female,name={\pref{Astrid} \surn{W}}}
                }
                child{
                    p\[id=Ma?\]{female,name={\pref{Ma} \surn{?}}}
                    g\[id=DaO\]{male,name={\pref{Da} \surn{O}}}
                    c\[id=AuW\]{male,name={\pref{Au} \surn{W}}}
                }
                child{  
                    g\[id=LoO\]{female,name={\pref{Lo} \surn{O}}}
                    p\[id=JoJ\]{male,name={\pref{Jo} \surn{J}}}
                }
            }
        }
%An
        c\[id=AnW,tikz={xshift=10mm}\]{female,name={\pref{An} \surn{W}}}
%Pe
        child{
            g\[id=PeW\]{male,name={\pref{Pe} \surn{W}}}
            p\[id=LuM\]{female,name={\pref{Lu} \nick{Lu} \surn{M}}}
            child{
                p\[id=NoJ\]{female,name={\pref{No} \surn{J}}}
                g\[id=GeW\]{male,name={\pref{Ge} \surn{W}}}
            }
            child{
                g\[id=StW\]{male,name={\pref{St} \surn{W}}}
                p\[id=Sy?\]{female,name={\pref{Sy} \surn{?}}}
                c\[id=KaW\]{female,name={\pref{Ka} \surn{W}}}
                c\[id=LiW\]{female,name={\pref{Li} Ma \surn{W}}}
            }
        }
%Jo        
        child\[id=JoJoW\]{
            p\[id=JoR\]{male,name={\pref{Jo} \surn{R}}}
            g\[id=JoW\]{female,name={\pref{Jo} An \nick{Jo} \surn{W}}}
            child{
                p\[id=MiS\]{male,name={\pref{Mi} \surn{S}}}
                g\[id=MoR\]{female,name={\pref{Mo} Ma \nick{Mo} \surn{R}}}
                child{
                    p\[id=ChF\]{male,name={\pref{Ch} \surn{F}}}
                    g\[id=MeS\]{female,name={\pref{Me} \surn{S}}}
                    c\[id=EmF\]{female,name={\pref{Em} \surn{F}}}
                }
                child{
                    g\[id=MaS\]{male,name={\pref{Ma} \surn{S}}}
                    p\[id=PiO\]{female,name={\pref{Pi} \surn{O}}}
                    c\[id=MaS\]{female,name={\pref{Ma} Ka \surn{S}}}
                }
            }
            child{
                p\[id=HoE\]{male,name={\pref{Ho} \surn{E}}}
                g\[id=PeR\]{female,name={\pref{Pe} Ma \nick{Pe} \surn{R}}}
                c\[id=ClE\]{female,name={\pref{Cl} \surn{E}}}
                c\[id=MaE\]{male,name={\pref{Ma} \surn{E}}}
            }
            child\[id=Fam_S,family box={colback=yellow!50}\]{
                p\[id=ThS\]{male,name={\pref{Th} \nick{To} \surn{S}}}
                g\[id=SuR\]{female,name={\pref{Su} Ma \nick{Su} \surn{R}}}
                c\[id=KaS\]{male,name={\pref{Ka} Mi \surn{S}}}
                c\[id=FeS\]{male,name={\pref{Fe} \surn{S}}}
                union\[id=Fam_S->K\]{
                    p\[id=FrK\]{male,name={\pref{Fr} He \surn{K}}}
                    c\[phantom\]{}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    child{
        g\[id=MaW\]{female,name={\pref{Ma} \surn{W}}}
        p\[id=MaR\]{male,name={\pref{Ma} \surn{R}}}
        c\[\]{??}
    }
}
```

[image: My Family Tree]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  Possible related is [Aligning nodes in tikz / genealogytree package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278853/124842)

Comment: Hello Bobyandbob, thanks for your answer. 
(and excuse me for not answering back)
Sadly the `set position`could not fix my problem.

Comment: I Found a (different) way to go, Explanation and Link: [Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444668/genealogytree-how-to-model-my-cousins)

Comment: Should i flag this question as an duplicat to your link? And is your questuion solved?